# How to install ssas AdventureWorks DW with SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, ssas, adventureworks

I am doing a proof of concept to explain the team using cubes improves the application's query performance. I am allowed to use VS 2008 BI tools. I am in need of the AdventureWorks2008R2 DW to be installed to write some mdx queries to query the cubes.

I have landed in [this](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/59211) official website that has a list of files and none of them help me to install the `AdventureworksDW` database. I have tried these methods

I have downloaded the adf file and while restoring thorough analysis server I get this error

> Backup and restore errors: Error during Restore/Synchronization: the backup >store directory is damaged, so the operation cannot locate or process the >'BackupLog' node from the backup store file while reading storage directory >header. (Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Analysis Services)
>   I have found and exe path but the exe is removed from Microsoft followed by installation errors.

This [link](http://www.ssas-info.com/analysis-services-faq/29-mgmt/242-how-install-adventure-works-dw-database-analysis-services-2005-sample-database) suggests an exe but is throwing error while installing.

Are there any better way to install it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I have found the answer myself.

Microsoft did not document this properly in their codeplex site.  I have posted this as an answer as it may help people searching for answers.

1) Download the `Adventureworks 2008 R2 Data File` and `AdventureWorksDW2008R2 Data File` from [this](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/59211) link and Restore it .
2) Download the zip file from this [link](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/88252) and extract it. It has folders enterprise and standard.  We have to choose one based on the sql server version we have.  In my case, Enterprise.  This zip file is the multidimensional model database query.  Microsoft has not added this in one documentation.
3) Open `sql server Business Intelligence Development studio` and open the solution file inside the enterprise folder.  If your sql server version is standard, open from standard folder.
4) Run the project.  The dropdown near the Run command should be deploy.

5) That's it.  We are done.